# What is a free, rounded font with bars on the capital "I"?

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, resource-recommendations

I'm looking for a rounded font similar to [Quicksand](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Quicksand), but I want to have a capital "I" that is distinguished from the lowercase "l", which means I need bars. I've found a font that does the job ([Monosten](https://www.colophon-foundry.org/typefaces/monosten/)), but unfortunately it's not free. I was wondering if there's a similar font to these two which is free and has this particular characteristic for the "I"?

Edit: I'm looking for a sans serif font in particular. I really like the look of Quicksand, but I was hoping to find one that just had the addition on the "I" as well.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. There are keywords you could search for - "monopaced, sans, rounded".  Not saying you will find one, but if Monostem is the right kind of font, then these key words apply to that font.

Comment: After a quick search I found [Courier Sans Prime](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/courier-prime-sans), which is free, and has a SIL Open Font License v1.10.

Comment: @BillyKerr I think your suggestion of Courier Sans Prime is very close to what I'm hoping for. If you add it as an answer, I will accept it!

Comment: Just be aware Courier is a monospaced font family, which may or may not work for your purpose.

Comment: OK, I added it at as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [Courier Prime Sans](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/courier-prime-sans), as long as you are aware it is a monospaced font and might not be suitable for everything. It's a free font with a SIL Open Font Licence v1.10.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you are looking for a font with a very specific characteristic you might want to try [Identifont's *"Fonts by Appearance"* search](http://www.identifont.com/identify.html).

[Here](http://www.identifont.com/identify?28+.+Y+8J+56V+1TM+8F+DG+8N+26RA+1KS+JPK+75+8W+7W+7P+8E+7S+8B+6X8+6X4+53K+1U6+1KI+79+1LA+1QY+7G+9Z) is a link to a search where I chose *"No (sans-serif)."* to the first question *"Do the characters have serifs?"*, *"Not sure"* to the following 25 questions and *Has serifs/bars.* to the 27th question *"What style is the upper-case letter 'I'?"*.

In the right side you can see some suggestions.

You can of course fine-tune your search by answering something different than *"Not sure"* to the questions. There seems to be more than 100 questions.

Comment: This is a very good site that I knew must exist, but didn't know where it was. I made some progress in my search using it, but I think Bill Kerr's suggestion of Courier Prime Sans is the best I've seen so far.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I think [Solway](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Solway?preview.text=I%27ll%20do%20it%20Illith&preview.text_type=custom&category=Serif) is the font that meets all of your needs:

- A serif capital I
- rounded
- [free](https://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=OFL) *

<sup>*This is not legal advice and I am not a lawyer. Please read the licence carefully.</sup>

Comment: Very close, but not *quite* what I'm looking for. I'll edit the main post to update my needs, but I guess I'm looking for a sans serif font that just has this edit on the "I". Unfortunately for Solway, it's a serif font so it is messing up the rest of the look I'm going for.